# Dynamic column count grid for responsive web design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am looking for a library that allows me to create a dynamic grid with optimal number of columns based on the browser window size.

So the following grid

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     5     |     6     |     7     |     8     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

should be resized and reordered like this when the window gets smaller.

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |     2     |     3     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     4     |     5     |     6     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     7     |     8     |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Does anyone know how something like this can be achieved for a responsive web design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with Bootstrap grid system?
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Get a link for Bootstrap CDN from here (https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) and link to your html and try this:

.html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">1</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">2</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">3</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">4</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">5</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">6</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">7</div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 square">8</div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.square {
  border:solid;
  border-color: WHATEVERCOLOR;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

If you are curious to know what class fix of ".col-md" or "col-sm" are, check "Grid Options" paragraph on this page:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Flexbox**

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q1mpk9s2/4/)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  li {
    flex: 0 1 33.333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Big screen
[image]

Small screen
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this approach however seems to have one downside. The ordering is columns first, resulting in 1 3 5 7 in the first row.

Comment: I am looking it at chrome and firefox and order is as you said.

Comment: ok, now it works. The fiddle link contained slightly different css code.